# deleting a cloned active record column id from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, grails-controller

i have deep cloned table entry but i want not to clone the id of the original as it will replace the original entry by having same id
so how to delete the id field from active record cloned object

this will copy the id of @item to @duplcate1 ,which i dont want

```
  @item = CuratedItem.find(params[:data_curated_id])
  @duplicate1 = @item.deep_clone
```

i tried this too

```
  @item = CuratedItem.find(params[:data_curated_id])
  @duplicate1 = @item.deep_clone except: :id
```

but this creates a id field with nil, which gives me an error of not null constraint error as id cant be null to be save in database

How to delete that id field from that cloned object

Comment: Does your `CuratedItem` model have any associations you want to clone too?

Comment: Yes. It has two "has_one" associations with two models.

Comment: Maybe this would do the job: `@duplicate1 = CuratedItem.create(@item.attributes.except('id'))`

Comment: [amoeba](https://github.com/amoeba-rb/amoeba) gem may helps you with this issue